# Filelist type react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

`interface IVideos {`

`lastModified: number,`

`name: string,`

`path: string,`

`size: number,`

`type: string,`

`webkitRelativePath: string`

`}`

`const [videos, setVideos] = useState<IVideos[] | null>([]);`

`<input type="file" onChange={(event) => setVideos(event.target.files)} />`

I'm getting this error in "setVideos()":

`Type 'FileList' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<IVideos[] | null>'.`

is my interface incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it necessary to create the IVideos interface? `File` and `FileList` are already predefined.

For example, here's an alternative that worked for me:

```
const [videos, setVideos] = useState<File[]>([]);
<input type="file" onChange={(event) => setVideos(Array.from(event.target.files ?? []))} />
```

Changes I made:

- Changed `IVideos[]` to `File[]` because it's already predefined, and that's an interface you don't have to maintain now.
- Removed the `| null`, so that you know it's always an array
- Used `Array.from(event.target.files` to force the FileList into an array
- Used `event.target.files ?? []` because Array.from can't take `null`, so if event.target.files returns null, we just replace it with an empty array.

Does that help, or is the use of the IVideos interface required?

Comment: IVideos is not required, thanks Julianna, I hadn't thought of that.